# Error with Bresenham's line algorithm

Tags: java, bresenham

I'm trying to fill a matrix with stars (*) to draw Bresenham's line, but when i'm printing out the thing the matrix is only filled with one star i don't know whats wrong. Language is Java

```
public class PtLine extends VectorObject{   // inherites from another class
private int bx;
private int by;
private int delX;
private int delY;

public PtLine(int id,int x,int y,int bx,int by){
     super(id,x,y);
     this.bx = bx;
     this.by = by;
     this.delX = this.bx-x;
     this.delY = this.by-y;

 }
 public void draw ( char [][] matrix ){    // filling the martic with stars
    int D = 2*delY - delX;
    matrix[x][y] = '*';
    int j = y;

    for (int i=x+1;i==bx;i++){
       if(D > 0){
          j+=1;
          matrix[i][j]='*';
          D = D + (2*delY-2*delX);
       }
      else{
         matrix[i][j]='*';
         D = D + (2*delY);
      } 
    } 
 }
```

}

The following code is when i'm trying to print out the matrix

```
  class Question3{
     public static void main ( String args [] ){


     char[][] matrix = new char[20][20];
     for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            matrix[y][x] = ' ';
         }
      }

     PtLine n = new PtLine(6,6,6,13,13);
     n.draw(matrix);
     for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[x][y]);
         }
         System.out.println();
     } 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have to change `i==bx` with `i!=bx`:

```
public void draw ( char [][] matrix ){    // filling the martic with stars
  int D = 2*delY - delX;
  matrix[x][y] = '*';
  int j = y;

  for (int i=x+1;i!=bx;i++){ // here
  ...
  }
}
```

The `for` loop continues while this condition is true. In your code loop finishes immediately at start, before the first iteration, because this condition is false.